# knockout.js mapping causing infinite recursion on IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, recursion, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm having endless recursion on IE by my knockout.js mapping. Can someone more familiar with KO to spot what am I doing wrong?

I have following knockout.js mapping:

```
        var mapping = {
            create: function(options) {
                return new MyViewModel(options.data);
            },
            'ChildItems': {
                create: function(options) {
                    return new ChildVM(options.data);
                }
            }
        }
```

When I render the page approx. 1 time out of 5 IE ends up with following infinite recursion stack(causing "SCRIPT28: Out of stack space"). IE's callstack:

```
    fromJS
    MyViewModel
    create
    Anonymous Function
    withProxyDependentObservable
    createCallback
    updateViewModel
    fromJS
    MyViewModel
    create
    Anonymous Function
    withProxyDependentObservable
    createCallback
    updateViewModel
        ...
```

My view model constructor:

```
 function MyViewModel(data) {
            var self = this;
            this.$type = 'MyViewModel';

            [some observables]         
            ...

            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this);
        }
```

Initializing of view model is done by calling json endpoint:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://my.end/point',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(payload),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(data) {
                    window.vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
                    ko.applyBindings(window.vm)
                    }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should divide your mapping object to 2 objects. Use first for mapping view model and second for children.

```
var mapping = {
            create: function(options) {
                return new MyViewModel(options.data);
            }
        }

var childrenMapping = {
                'ChildItems': {
                    create: function(options) {
                        return new ChildVM(options.data);
                    }
                }
}
```

Your ajax request remain the same. Update MyViewModel function to use childrenMapping :

```
 function MyViewModel(data) {
            var self = this;
            this.$type = 'MyViewModel';

            [some observables]         
            ...

            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, childrenMapping, this);
        }
```

The root cause of the issue is recursive calling of mapping. When you call `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);` knockout calls create rule where creates MyViewModel object. In MyViewModel's constructor you call `ko.mapping.fromJS` due to the using of the same mapping options knockout calls the same create rule that creates MyViewModel object where `ko.mapping.fromJS` is called with the same options.

Comment: Thanks this actually solved the problem. Could you explain what was the actual issue that caused recursion in the first place with IE?

Comment: What really confuses me is why this behavior is only happening with IE and even more confusing is that it happens only in 30-40% of cases?

Comment: Maybe browsers somehow prevent this.