# knockoutjs mapping plugin update complex object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have the following mapping for a custom object,

```
var mapping = {

    'At': {
        create: function (options) {
            debugger
            return new myAt(options.data);
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the custom object,

```
var myAt = function (data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
    var self = this;
    this.AddOthRev = function (index) {
        var cpy = new myRevEx({ Desc: '', Y1: '', Y2: '', Y3: '', Y4: '', Y5: '',Total:'' });
        this.OthRevLst.push(cpy);
    }

    this.RemoveOthRev = function (index) {
        self.OthRevLst.remove(index);
    }


    this.ShowCustFi = function (index) {

        viewModel.At().forEach(function (item) {
            item.ActiveTab(false);
        });

        index.ActiveTab(true);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }


    this.TotalPrcnt = ko.pureComputed({
        read: function () {
            return this.EqtyPrcnt() + this.EtfPrcnt();
        },
        write: function (value) { this.TotalPrcnt(value); },
        owner: this
    });
}

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
```

until this everything works fine...

Now I want to update this viewmodel with data JSON data from server. I am not sure how I do that with the custom mapping I have.

I am doing `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, viewModel);` but that throws some error.

Comment: What is the "some error"?

Comment: @james Thorpe... The "some error" is "JavaScript runtime error: Out of stack space".

Comment: The error sounds like infinite recursion, and you've got your `ko.mapping.fromJS` calling `ko.mapping.fromJS` (via the At constructor). I can't tell if this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006433/knockout-js-mapping-causing-infinite-recursion-on-ie9